# Gitlab CI/CD pipeline issue

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have faced an issue with gitlab ci pipeline.
When I push / commit anything to the repo the pipeline doesn't gets triggered automatically. I have to manually run the pipeline on every commit.
Even the gitlab issues blog is not able to answer my question.
Is there anyone who had faced this issue and knows the solution to this?

Comment: Please add some information. what CI you use? have you set webhooks?

Comment: No i haven't set any web hooks. Pipeline will have get formed after i push or commit (default behavior of gitlab) but in my case it wasn't

Comment: Do you have a .gitlab-ci.yml file into your root project folder? (with at least one simple stage like "test" or "build" for example)